# Customizing wdio test errors by using the browser.on

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

According to wdio's documentation found [here](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/eventhandling.html) I should be allowed to handle an error using

`browser.on('error', (err)=>{ console.log('do something') })`

However, when I do this, nothing happens it isn't executed when the test fails, which from my understanding should have happened.

Am I doing this wrong? If so, how can I use the `.on` function to handle the test fails or errors my own way? I do know I can use try/catch blocks, but I would like something cleaner that is just called every time tests fail or there is an error.

Edit: as requested, added some code to show the error

```
browser.on('error', () => {
     console.log('do something about the error')
})

it('should do something', function () {
     const nonExistingElement = browser.getText('.idontexist')
     assert.deepStrictEqual(nonExistingElement, 'Say something that isnt there')
})
```

What I would like to do is for the callback function of browser.on be executed whenever an error or failed test occur, in this case, I am trying to get the text of an element that doesn't exist, so naturally I will get the whole

> element (".idontexist") still not existing after 500ms

But before that, as it happens I would also like to get the:

> do something about the error

So far, the alternative to this, would be to put a try and catch block in my it block and do a `browser.emit('error', 'Error')`, which I would like to avoid so that I don't have to repeat it every single test.

Comment: Code an intentional error and then see if it works. Please add the actual code you are using to test this.

Comment: @JeffC, as requested I added the code and some details regarding what happens.